# Cosa significa "trascinare con sé di tutto" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *La frantumaglia* (nuova edizione ampliata 2016, E/O) di Elena Ferrante ho incontrato il testo che segue:

> L'amicizia femminile è stata lasciata senza regole. Non le sono
>   imposte nemmeno quelle maschili, ed è tuttora un territorio con codici
>   fragili dove amare (la parola amicizia ha a che fare, nella nostra
>   lingua, con amore), **trascina con sé di tutto**, sentimenti elevati e
>   pulsioni ignobili.

Secondo me c'è anche un problema di punteggiature, ma comunque vorrei sapere che significa in questo caso questo verbo "trascinare". Suppongo che "amare" sia il soggetto in questa frase ma non ne sono sicuro 100%.

"Trascinare con sé di tutto" mi fa immaginare un fiume pieno che trascina tutte le cose che si trova nel suo corso, ma non riesco a collegare questa azione con oggetti che seguono, cioè "sentimenti elevati e pulsioni ignobili". Poi che c'entra "amare"?

Grazie!

Comment: Forse vuol dire "l'azione amare causa di tutto, da sentimenti elevati fino a pulsioni ignobili"?  

Il Treccani dice "In espressioni fig.: t. con sé, portare come conseguenza"
http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trascinare/

Comment: Sì, più o meno il significato è quello.

Comment: Grazie per la risposta.

Comment: Direi che l'analogia è con una valanga o un'inondazione che “trascina qualsiasi cosa trovi”; ci vorrebbero due punti, invece della virgola. Certo che EF scrive proprio male.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salve!

Nel testo  “…trascina con sé di tutto, sentimenti elevati e pulsioni ignobili”   il verbo “trascinare” ha proprio il senso di un fiume in piena che trascina nelle sue acque qualsiasi cosa trovi lungo il suo percorso.

Quanto all’infinito presente attivo  “amare” in “…dove amare ….. trascina con sé di tutto, sentimenti elevati e pulsioni ignobili”, esso è esattamente il soggetto di “trascina con sé..”, dato che la scrittrice vuole sottolineare che “l’amicizia femminile ……è tuttora un territorio con codici fragili dove amare …. trascina con sé di tutto, sentimenti elevati e pulsioni ignobili”, intendendo dire che, a suo parere,  il sentimento dell’amore può essere contemporaneamente  elevato e ignobile.

Infine, la virgola posta  dopo  il testo in parentesi “(la parola amicizia ha a che fare, nella nostra lingua, con amore)” è fuori luogo, dato che il soggetto  “amare” non può essere separato da “trascina “ che è il suo verbo.

Aggiungo che, al posto della virgola dopo “…. trascina con sé di tutto”, avrebbero potuto esserci i due punti e quindi il testo avrebbe potuto essere:
”L'amicizia femminile è stata lasciata senza regole. Non le sono imposte nemmeno quelle maschili, ed è tuttora un territorio con codici fragili dove amare (la parola amicizia ha a che fare, nella nostra lingua, con amore) trascina con sé di tutto: sentimenti elevati e pulsioni ignobili”.

Cordiali saluti.

Comment: Grazie mille per la risposta dettagliata, tanto dettagliata che non mi meraviglierei anche se fosse Lei Elena Ferrante in persona o il suo editore di fiducia ;-)